# Tkinter label textvariable does not track StringVar while thread updates it

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

**Edited: reduced problem to minimal reproducible example.**

I am making an idle game, so I want current amount of money and current income per second to be tracked in the game window. I am using tkinter to create the GUI, and I make income calculations in a separate daemon thread.

When I launch the game and purchase units, they add money as intended and the current balance is tracked as intended. I have checked the income variable (tk.IntVar()) and confirmed that it is properly updated with the current income/s as well.

However, the tkinter label that tracks balance updates properly, while the income/s label does **not**. It stays at "0/s" at all times.

Here is the code, reduced to include one unit and the option to purchase them:

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("test")

class Currency:
    """For objects that track currency stashes and income."""

    def __init__(self, currency_name, currency_type):
        self.name = currency_name
        self.value = tk.IntVar(window, 0)
        self.income = tk.IntVar(window, 0)
        self.type = currency_type
        self.lbl_name = tk.Label(window,
                                 text=("{0}:".format(self.name)),
                                 justify=tk.LEFT)
        self.lbl_value = tk.Label(window, textvariable=self.value)
        self.lbl_income = tk.Label(window,
                                   textvariable=tk.StringVar(window,
                                                             str(self.income.get())+"/s"),
                                   justify=tk.RIGHT)
"""
The label I have a problem with.
"""


unit_list = []
influence = Currency(
    'Influence',
    'influence')


class IncomeUnit:
    """For sources of passive income"""

    def __init__(self, name, base_inc, unit_type, cost_type):
        self.name = name
        self.inc = base_inc
        self.number = tk.IntVar(window, 0)
        self.type = unit_type
        self.cost_type = cost_type
        self.lbl_name = tk.Label(window, text=("{0}:".format(self.name)),
                                 justify=tk.LEFT)
        self.lbl_number = tk.Label(window, textvariable=self.number)
        unit_list.append(self)
        self.buysell_1 = tk.Button(window, text="1", command=self.buy)

    def buy(self):  # implement subtracting costs
        self.number.set(self.number.get() + 1)


stitched = IncomeUnit(
    'Stitched',  # Name of the unit
    1,  # Base income of the unit
    'influence',
    'research'
    )

influence.lbl_name.grid(column=0, row=1)
influence.lbl_value.grid(column=1, row=1)
influence.lbl_income.grid(column=0, row=2)

top_rows = 6  # Change when you add more stuff on top. Rearranges unit grid.
for i in range(len(unit_list)):
    unit_list[i].lbl_name.grid(column=0 if i < 8 else 6,
                               row=i * 2 + top_rows if i < 8 else (i - 8) * 2 + top_rows,
                               sticky=tk.W)
    unit_list[i].lbl_number.grid(column=1 if i < 8 else 7,
                                 row=i * 2 + top_rows if i < 8 else (i - 8) * 2 + top_rows,
                                 sticky=tk.W)
    unit_list[i].buysell_1.grid(column=2 if i < 8 else 8,
                                row=i * 2 + top_rows if i < 8 else (i - 8) * 2 + top_rows,
                                sticky=tk.W)

def allincome():
    while True:
        temp_inc = 0
        for un in range(len(unit_list)):
            if unit_list[un].type == influence.type:
                influence.value.set(influence.value.get() +
                                    unit_list[un].inc *
                                    unit_list[un].number.get())
            temp_inc += unit_list[un].inc * unit_list[un].number.get()
            influence.income.set(temp_inc)
        print(temp_inc)
"""Prints the correct value"""
        print(influence.income.get())
"""Prints the correct value"""
        time.sleep(1)


income_thread = threading.Thread(None, allincome, daemon=True)
income_thread.start()


window.mainloop()
```

This loop calculates income per second and updates the label variables with the current data.

Is there something I am missing that prevents self.lbl_income from updating?

Comment: Please try to reduce all of that code down to a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley updated question. Not sure if it's good practice to @ after clarifying questions, sorry if it's not.

Comment: using @ is d way we get the notification, or else we dont get notified for comments :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. After some experimenting, I found that textvariable plays nice only if I directly set it as:

```
textvariable=self.income
```

, while defining

```
self.income = tk.StringVar(window, '0/s')
```

and updating it as

```
influence.income.set(str(temp_inc)+'/s')
```